# Android - writing apps for not-yet-released devices

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am looking to write an Android app for a device that has not been released to the market yet, and so I will not have the hardware to test upon.  I have created an AVD (Android Virtual Device) with as much information as is currently available on the web, so assume that this is as like the device as is possible to get.

However, does anyone have any tips or ideas to make the process of developing for this platform as easy as possible?  My current apps have been for personal use on my own phone, so can test performance on the hardware etc. which is obviously not possible in this case.  Any gotchas to watch out for (apart from the possibility of the device never being released..!!)

Comment: Why is this device so special that you do not mention a feature of it? As long as you follow the SDK and don't take use of non-documented APIs I think it will be fine.

Comment: I am writing an app for the USS Enterprise, any gotchas to watch out for?

Comment: @Marko - Time travel may cause a few conceptual issues...but nothing a good captain can't deal with!

Comment: @Pentium10 - That's what I'm hoping...but if people have experience of doing this, I'd rather learn from their mistakes than my own...although I'm sure I'll make plenty along the way.
As for the device, it's one of the tablet-type devices hoping to come to the market this year.

Comment: I second what I have stated as long as you follow the SDK and don't take use of non-documented APIs it will be fine. If there will be any restrictions, it will be officially released, and you will have to follow those as your app won't be accepted in Market

Comment: @Pentium10 I don't think counts if you second your own statement, so I will second it for you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow the SDK.
AVD behaves similar to a real device. I really can't think of something it behaved different on a device and on the AVD.

The **only** device that brought me trouble is the HTC Hero, first phone with HTC Sense. It didn't follow the SDK and they were calls that weren't there. Newer phones with HTC sense doesn't have this issue, as far as I can tell.